# how to add extension to all files in a list

Tags: list, powershell, batch-rename

how do i add an extension to my files in a list?

```
$proj_files = (
"C:\test\122\338\7\1326647",
"C:\test\122\339\8\1326650"
)


ForEach ($file in $proj_files) {
$filenew = $file.Name + ".jpg"
Rename-Item $file $filenew
}
```

as with this I can get to add extensions to it, but it also then removes the name of the file so how do I just add the extension to it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$filenew` should just be ".jpg" above.  This is because `$file.Name` should be blank.  The `$file` object is a single string from the array of strings in `$proj_files`.  Remove `.Name` and it will probably work fine.

If you want to know what `$file` has, or is, pipe it to `| Get-Member`.